# Как применить анимацию для всех элементов с классом 'snow'?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

На странице есть пара элементов, к которым мне нужно применить анимацию. Я перебираю элементы через цикл `for`, но почему-то анимация не срабатывает. Буду признателен за помощь.

**html:**

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
   <div class="item"><canvas class="snow"></canvas></div>
   <div class="item"><canvas class="snow"></canvas></div>
   <div class="item"><canvas class="snow"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
if ($(".snow").length) {
    window.onload = function() {

        var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('.snow');
        for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
            var ctx = canvas[i].getContext("2d");
            canvas[i].width = W;
            canvas[i].height = H;
            var W = window.innerWidth;
            var H = window.innerHeight;
            var mp = 25;
            var particles = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
                particles.push({
                    x : Math.random() * W,
                    y : Math.random() * H,
                    r : Math.random() * 4 + 1,
                    d : Math.random() * mp
                })
            }

            function draw() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
                ctx.beginPath();
                for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
                    var p = particles[i];
                    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                }
                ctx.fill();
                update();
            }

            var angle = 0;
            function update() {
                angle += 0.01;
                for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
                    var p = particles[i];
                    p.y += Math.cos(angle + p.d) + 1 + p.r / 2;
                    p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;
                    if (p.x > W + 5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H) {
                        if (i % 3 > 0) {
                            particles[i] = {
                                x : Math.random() * W,
                                y : -10,
                                r : p.r,
                                d : p.d
                            };
                        } else {
                            if (Math.sin(angle) > 0) {
                                particles[i] = {
                                    x : -5,
                                    y : Math.random() * H,
                                    r : p.r,
                                    d : p.d
                                };
                            } else {
                                particles[i] = {
                                    x : W + 5,
                                    y : Math.random() * H,
                                    r : p.r,
                                    d : p.d
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            setInterval(draw, 33);
        }
    }
}

$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel(
        {
            items : 1,
            autoplay : true,
            autoplayTimeout : 10000,
            mouseDrag : false,
            loop : true,
            nav : true,
            navText : [ "<i class='fa fa-angle-up'></i>",
                    "<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>" ],
            animateOut : 'fadeOut',
            animateIn : 'fadeIn',
            dots : true,
            responsive : {
                768 : {
                    dots : false
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: обновите вопрос и дайте кусок вашего `html`.

Comment: приблизительно получилось, сейчас у меня снег идет))), только я не пойму зачем вам второй и третий `convas`? эту часть объясните мне? что бы ответ был полным?

Comment: при добавлении пользователем фото через админ панел, он мог так же поставь какойнить канвас еффект к этому изображнию, ну один из них снег, может быть один слайдер с таким а может быть и 10

Comment: я использую owl-carousel и так как я ставлю зацикливание оно создает item-cloned и тд... ну и тут я гдето делаю ошибку

Comment: вы посмотрели ответ?

Comment: да посмотрел, но не работает, срабатывает только на 1 слайде на остальных нет

Comment: сейчас пересмотрю ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61531/discussion-between-dima-vleskov-and-razmik-galstyan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первую ошибку которую я увидел это было здесь:

```
canvas[i].width = W;
canvas[i].height = H;
var W = window.innerWidth;
var H = window.innerHeight;
```

Вы работаете с переменными `W` и `H` до их инициализации.

И второе у вас и снег белый и фон. ну может это просто у меня так потому что вы дали кусок кода.

Обнаружил еще 2 ошибки.

Вы в этом `for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {` цикле перезаписываете переменную `i` и ее значение становиться `25`, после этого внешний цикл `for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {` перестает работать после первой итерации.

И последняя то что функции `draw` и `update` надо вынести за приделы цикла и в функции `draw` я всегда передаю параметр `ctx`.

Вот код который уже работает на трех `convas`-ах.

---

```html
<style>    
    body{
        background: black;
    }    
</style>
<div class="owl-carousel">
   <div class="item"><canvas class="snow"></canvas></div>
   <div class="item"><canvas class="snow"></canvas></div>
   <div class="item"><canvas class="snow"></canvas></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        let W = window.innerWidth;
        let H = window.innerHeight;
        if ($(".snow").length > 0){
            var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('.snow');
            for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
                let ctx = canvas[i].getContext("2d");                
                canvas[i].width = W;
                canvas[i].height = H;
                var mp = 25;
                var particles = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < mp; j++) {
                    particles.push({
                        x: Math.random()*W, 
                        y: Math.random()*H,
                        r: Math.random()*4+1, 
                        d: Math.random()*mp 
                    });
                }                
               setInterval(function (){draw(ctx);}, 33);
            }
            function draw(ctx) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
                ctx.beginPath();
                for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
                {
                    var p = particles[i];
                    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                }
                ctx.fill();
                update();
            }

            var angle = 0;
            function update() {
                angle += 0.01;
                for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
                    var p = particles[i];
                    p.y += Math.cos(angle+p.d) + 1 + p.r/2;
                    p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;
                    if(p.x > W+5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H) {
                        if(i%3 > 0) {
                            particles[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: -10, r: p.r, d: p.d};
                        } else{
                            if (Math.sin(angle) > 0){
                                particles[i] = {x: -5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.r, d: p.d};
                            }
                            else {
                                particles[i] = {x: W+5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.r, d: p.d};
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: всё работает отлично, спасибо